# react js how to prevent arrow keys from switching controls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, controls, key-bindings

I am working on react browser-based game where a player can select a unit to place on a battlefield, and then he can use the arrow keys to move the unit around on a map.

The problem is that the list of units is a react radio group, and that pressing the arrow keys also switches the focus from the one radio button to the next, which causes a different unit to be selected by the very same action that was supposed to (and does) move the initial unit, so the whole thing becomes quite confusing.

I use event listeners bound to the `componentDidMount` method to bind the arrow keys to move the unit.

```
componentDidMount(){
  ...
  document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown.bind(this));
  document.addEventListener("keyup", this.handleKeyUp.bind(this));
```

While there may be a number of ways to solve this, I would prefer to simply disable the switching of radio-button using the arrow keys. Does anyone know how to turn that off?

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@ericclemmons/react-event-preventdefault-78c28c950e46), but it mostly goes over my head, and besides I am still hoping there is an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[React suggest to use `preventDefault` statement](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) rather than using return false:

```
handleKeyDown = (e) => {
 //... rest of your code
 e.preventDefault()
}
```

Also, you don't need to bind `addEventListener` inside componentDidMount hook. The event will be called from `event binding` of component.

Example:

```
<YourComponent onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} />
```

Comment: Where in the documentation it is mentioned? Could you point me?

Comment: Linked to the post.

Comment: I see ... _Another difference is that you cannot return false to prevent default behavior in React. You must call preventDefault explicitly._

Comment: Thanks @BhojendraRauniyar - that works! About your suggestion `onKeyDown` vs `addEventListener`: In my case, the onKey events manipulate variables (unit positions) that are local within the page that is being rendered and are not currently available at the higher level from where the page instance is called. Therefore the onKey functions are also not available at a higher level to attach to the onKey properties as per your suggestion. I tried to add the onKey to the outer-most component of my page (a `<div>`), but that had no effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: call the outer component onKey event in the child component using this.props.onKey...

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Do you mean like `render (<Battlefield onKey={this.props.onKey} /> )` does the `this`, in this case, not refer to the outer component? That would be problematic, because I cannot define the onKey function there, since the function needs to manipulate variables that are local in the inner component...

Comment: sorry, I din't get you properly. can you rephrase your question?